# Textbox Click not working after page reload

Tags: javascript, validation, onclick, textbox, alert

On my webpage, there is an alert box that will trigger when I click on a button without providing valid data. At the moment, the alert box appears and I accidentally reloaded the webpage without closing it. But after reloading, I couldn't edit or type anything in all the textboxes, but there is no issue with selecting a list or checking a box.

What actions can I take to prevent this?

Comment: Your question is lacking a lot of context. Please view this and try to edit your question with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask